# A way to "No cache" with Php on part of my page?

Tags: php, forms, browser-cache

I have a form on a page of my site. I have a table which echos from submit form, which I would like to no cache because when you enter form the cached version is showed and not updated.  Is there a better way to no cache the page rather than the meta tags?

The code I'm using now is

```
       <?php
       $query='select * from article order by `article`.`time` DESC LIMIT 10';
       $result=mysql_query($query); 
       echo '<table class="mytable" width="1000px" border="0">';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
    echo "<td><a href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['title']."</a> - ".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['class']."</td></tr>";
}
echo '<table>';
       ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

It is more complex, but you could put your "non-cached" data in an `iframe` and embed the iframe within your primary document.

Unless your main page is extremely large, however, I doubt it is worth the effort just to cache part of a page.  Usually if your `css`, `javascript` and `images` are all external, they should be cached normally and make up the bulk of your code.

Comment: This is the ONLY answer that answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

These php headers wil prevent client side caching of your php output:

```
<?php
//no  cache headers 
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2012 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: That will prevent caching of the *entire page.*  The OP was looking to cache part, not cache the rest.

Comment: **12012** should be **2012**

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

And cache the rest using `ob` buffering.